Ngrx action group: automatic way to rewrite old Actions
I have over 800 Actions in my project written in the old form:
export const GetAction = createAction(
  '[BOOK] GET',

  props<{
    filter: BookFilterModel,
  }>(),
);

export const GetFailAction = createAction(
  '[BOOK] GET_FAIL',
);

export const GetSuccessAction = createAction(
  '[BOOK] GET_SUCCESS',

  props<{
    book: BookModel,
  }>(),
);

Is there a way to rewrite them to Action Group automatically?
